# Parsing this Grammar From top to down the tree

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction

please take a look at grammar below :

```
S=>AB
A=>aA | epsilon
B=>bB | b
```

This grammar will generate **ab** or **aaaab** or **aaabbbbbbbb** and so on ...

I want to write a parser for that which is Recursive Descent parser with one character as lookahead .here is the code :

```
void ParseS()
{
    if(lookahead=="a")
    {
        GetNext();
        ParseA();

        if(lookahead=="b")
        {
            GetNext();  
            ParseB();
        }
        else
        {
            Error("expected 'b' at " + (index+1).ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Error("expected 'a' at " + (index + 1).ToString());
    }
}
void ParseA()
{
    if (lookahead == "a")
    {

        ParseA();
    }
    else {  }


}
void ParseB()
{
    if (lookahead == "b")
    {
        GetNext();
        ParseB();
    }
    else
    {
        Error("expected 'b' at " + (index + 1).ToString());
    }
}
```

Where is the error?

Updated Code from Comments , works nice :

```
    void ParseS()
    {
        if(lookahead=="a")
        {

            ParseA();

            if(lookahead=="b")
            {

                ParseB();
            }
            else
            {
                Error("expected 'b' at " + (index+1).ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Error("expected 'a' at " + (index + 1).ToString());
        }
    }
    void ParseA()
    {

        if (lookahead == "a")
        {
            GetNext();
            ParseA();
        }
        else {  }


    }
    void ParseB()
    {

        if (lookahead == "b")
        {
            GetNext();
            ParseB();
        }
        else if (lookahead != "$")
        {
            Error("expected 'b' at " + (index + 1).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: top down parsing I mean , not regex.

Comment: You are not showing your `GetNext` code but it looks like you have asymmetry: if lookahead == "a" you call ParseA(), but if lookahead == "b" you call GetNext() before calling ParseB(); that does not seem right.

Comment: I get that. I'm mostly just riffing on how a regex is thousands of times shorter. But direct interpretation of the regex also gives rise to a simpler top-down parser using loops, possibly condensed into a single function.

Comment: @delnan , understanding parsers is my objective, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Keep GetNext in ParseA and ParseB and remove other

Comment: I agree with Dieter - your S production does not consume terminals directly so neither should your ParseS() function.